# Meteor app facebook login blocked frame

Tags: facebook, meteor, accounts

When my app tries to use facebook login, the process gets blocked by :

```
Blocked a frame with origin "http://<server.ip>" from accessing a frame    
with origin "http://<my.domain>". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
```

Related questions don't really help as they are related to frames from facebook?
Both ip and domain are listed as valid redirect URI in facebook.

It seems to stop the facebook popup to close.

Comment: That is a pretty normal message, coming from what the Facebook JS SDK tries to do. But it should not generally stop your app from working.

Comment: The facebook popup never closes after that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further testing it seems that in fact the handshake actually works, but that the popup doesn't close. I'm going to ask another question with those infos.