# Meteor app - facebook login - popup doesn't close

Tags: facebook, meteor, user-accounts

My meteor app login with facebook seems to work properly except that the login popup never closes. The popup window stays open until the app is reloaded. I don't even where to start to debug this...
The popup is blank and the inspect reveals :

```
<p id="completedText" style="display:none;">
    Login completed. <a href="#" onclick="window.close()">
      Click here</a> to close this window.
  </p>
```

The style=display:none is probably why the popup appears blank but I don't know how to update that style. Also, if I perform a window.close() from the console, the popup disappears but the app doesn't register the login.

BTW, this bug only appears when I use my app from my domain name, when I call it from the IP address, it works just fine.

Comment: Can you please tell me which packages you use? You can close it manually with JQuery like $('.elementClass').hide() but you should check if there are errors and hide it if there aren't any.

Comment: accounts-facebook, accounts-ui, service-configuration are the packages relevant to this issue I think.

there is an error related to blocked frame : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35891773/meteor-app-facebook-login-blocked-frame, but apparently it shouldn't prevent the window to close?

Comment: @Luna actually the facebbok popup just doesn't display the button that should allow the user to close the window : <p id="completedText" style="display:none;">
    Login completed. <a href="#" onclick="window.close()">
      Click here</a> to close this window.
  </p>

Comment: @MathieuK. did you find any solution to the problem? I am facing same problem. Twitter works fine for me but Facebook doesn't close popup due to which user is not registered.

Comment: I posted my solution as an answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is a known bug with iOS and can be solved by changing the loginStyle parameters:

> Usually, the popup-based flow is preferable because the user will not have to reload your whole app at the end of the login flow. However, the popup-based flow requires browser features such as window.close and window.opener that are not available in all mobile environments. In particular, we recommend using Meteor.loginWith({ loginStyle: "redirect" }) in the following environments:
>
> Inside UIWebViews (when your app is loaded inside a mobile app)
> In Safari on iOS8 (window.close is not supported due to a bug)

[Meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html#popup-vs-redirect-flow)

Comment: but loginStyle cannot be changed for apps as it is hardcoded to popup.

Comment: no it is not. you can change it when you setup a particular service or in mongo if you are already setup.

Comment: @Davinder You are kind of right when the app is packaged as hybrid Cordova app: the `loginStyle` no longer applies and the app always uses a new InAppBrowser window. Unfortunately that Cordova plugin had a bug specifically in such situations. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40105055/meteor-social-login-blank-page-on-oauth2-login-using-fb-or-google/44652947#44652947

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same issue, when I started using accounts-google.

It was because I was mixing **http** and **https** in my redirect URL.